# Executable only partially works

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pyinstaller

I'm using python 3.6.8. I have a simple program that scrapes the HTML of 4 websites and pickles the info I need into individual files. and this program works fine in the interpreter. I'm using `pyinstaller` to turn it into an executable.

**The problem:**
Making the python file into an executable works without any problems or errors, but when I run the executable it goes through the first website and pickles the info just fine, but only gets part-way into pickling the next file and then closes. It doesn't show any errors.

**What I've tried:** I made the executable again but in Linux and it worked fine there. I reinstalled python and all the modules on windows but that didn't fix it. I ran it in the console to see if it spit out any errors, which it didn't.

I don't know what to try next.

Comment: Executables made for Linux generally don't run on Windows. Please provide a minimal, reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: i remade the executable in Linux to see if it worked there. it did. the exe that i compiled in windows however isn't working in windows.

Comment: Still, it's unlikely anyone can help you unless they can reproduce the problem on their Windows machines, hence the crucial need for an [mre] from you in your question. If you can't do that, the you're only recourse will be to add calls to `print()` to your code in order to determine what's it doing and where it quits executing.

Comment: This type of problem is typically a matter of some environment variable, working directory or available module being different for the executable than it is for what you're running from the IDE/interpreter. Check those, add more logging to your application and if you are still stumped, try to come up with a minimal example that has the same issue, that you can share here.

Comment: OK, understood—but it's not really a suitable question for SO. Regardless, since it's failing on the second site, try skipping the first one and see what happens. Maybe there's something about the contents of the second one that's causing the issue. This will let you narrow the cause down and potentially speed-up the debugging process.